# How to organise Realm Storage structure in the right way

Tags: android, realm

My question concerns the basic principles of creating Realm Storage.

Let's assume I'm creating hackneyed DB which contains **articles** and **authors**.

If I used SQLite engine, I'd do normalisation and create schema with 2 table: Articles and Authors with primary key `author_id` in the secon table. Please see

[image: picture1]

On the other hand, I guess that sticking to Document-Oriented DB approach, I should make tree-like structure. Please see

[image: picture2].

- The question is what approach should I take and why?
- Will the storage size grow exponentially in the second case and what approach is more judicious in terms of performance?

Answer from the Realm team would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christian from Realm here.
I would go with the second approach as the Java API's have been designed to work like a Document/Object store, so you would get the best API experience that way. It would also give you the best performance as the more work you let the API do for you the better. Maintaining your own keys will always be slower.

You don't have to worry about the size in either case as Realm internally does a lot to compact the data. If you are interested you can read more here: http://realm.io/news/introducing-realm/

Comment: I both understand the Q&A, but one thing remains unclear to me: in this way (2nd option) how many author objects are created? I guess the answer is either 2 or 4, but if 2 (which I find more convenient) how realm know we do not want 4 authors? How are unique fields are managed? Is there a way to specify this (id, or uniqueness) to Realm either from JSON or Java API?